# How to get all the contacts in which all their associated email accounts are marked as invalid?

Tags: mysql

Given the following scheme

```
CREATE TABLE contacts (
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    first_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    last_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(Id)
);

CREATE TABLE email_addresses (
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    email_address VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    invalid_email tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(Id)
);

CREATE TABLE email_addr_bean_rel (
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    email_address_id VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    contact_id VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    bean_module VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(Id)
);
```

I want to get all the contacts where all their associated emails have the value of the `invalid_email` field to `false`

Given the following records

```
INSERT INTO contacts
    (id, first_name, last_name)
VALUES
    (1, 'Jill', 'Valentine'),
    (2, 'Ada', 'Wong'),
    (3, 'Leon', 'Kennedy')
;

INSERT INTO email_addresses
    (id, email_address, invalid_email)
VALUES
    (1, 'jill.valentine@racoon-city.pod.gob', true),
    (2, 'ada.wong@umbrella.com', true),
    (3, 'leon.kennedy@racoon-city.pod.gob', false),
    (4, 'rebeca.chambers@racoon-city.pod.gob', false)
;

INSERT INTO email_addr_bean_rel
    (id, email_address_id, contact_id, bean_module)
VALUES
    (1, '1', 1, 'contacts'),
    (2, '2', 2, 'contacts'),
    (3, '3', 2, 'contacts'),
    (4, '4', 3, 'contacts')
;
```

The expected results are

(1, 'Jill', 'Valentine'),

Because Ada has two email accounts, one valid and one invalid, and the condition is that all email accounts associated with the contact must be invalid. Leon because he has only one account associated and it is valid

The approach I have made is the following

```
SELECT eabr.contact_id
    FROM email_addr_bean_rel eabr
    JOIN email_addresses ea ON eabr.email_address_id = ea.id
    WHERE ea.invalid_email = false
```

I try to obtain the invalid accounts first, it could be a subquery. but I understand I must first obtain a summary in which all the accounts are invalid

Thanks in advance for any ideas

Comment: You're missing the comma after `desde`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could `GROUP BY` the contact and check for `MIN(invalid_email)`:

```
SELECT c.*
FROM contacts c
JOIN email_addr_bean_rel eabr ON c.id = eabr.contact_id
JOIN email_addresses ea ON eabr.email_address_id = ea.id
GROUP BY c.id
HAVING MIN(ea.invalid_email) = 1;
```

Outputs:

| id | first_name | last_name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Jill | Valentine |

Here's a [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/5OEtwd_Z).